# Невозможно преобразование к типу Число 1С

Tags: 1с

При проведении документа происходит ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом я не понимаю почему, ведь все эти заначения числовые.

Сама База:https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ieWL/5igbVMn8d

Код в котором происходит ошибка расположен в общем модуле и вызывается в модуле документа НачисленияСотрудникам.

Comment: Вероятно ВыборкаРезультата.Норма или .Факт равняется NULL; Предполагаю что не заполнен график рабочего времени или календарь;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй в режиме отладки посмотреть, что именно передается в норме и факте. Есть вероятность что там не инициализированное значение(NULL), из-за этого ошибка.